# ¿Por qué me imprime resultados repetidos de una lista de este código?

Tags: python, random

Acabo de terminar un código en el que se imprimen los múltiplos de un número aleatorio.

Lo que hace el código es imprimir en un txt la pregunta, las opciones a elegir y la respuesta correcta, pero esta última se imprime aparte.

Algo así:

```
1.-¿Cuál de los siguientes números es un múltiplo de 26?
a) 102     b) 61     c) 52     d) 60
------------------------------------
1.-102
```

**Problema:**
Al momento de imprimirlo se me almacena el resultado erróneo, me arroja un resultado diferente al que debería ser la variable `op=choice(result)`
El resultado correcto es el que se almacena en `result_total.append(op)`
Hay 6 posibles respuestas que se almacenaron en `result_total` y solo una debe ser almacenada en cada iteración, pero al hacer otra iteración se vuelve a elegir otra al azar.

Mi código:

```
from random import randint, choice, shuffle
result_total=[] #Se crea un lista en donde se almacenan los resultados correctos
archivo=open('Ejercicio1.11.txt', 'w') #Se abre un archivo donde se almacenan los ejercicios
insert=int(input('Valor: '))
up=0 #Se añade un contador para indicar el número de ejercicio
for o in range(insert): #Se crea un bucle para hacer una secuencia en el rango que el usuario lo indique en la consola
    value=1 #Con este contador determino la cantidad de veces que se imprime el bucle z
    for z in range(value): #Se crea otro bucle para comenzar a iterar los múltiplos del mismo número
        up+=1 #El flujo de ejecución comienza a sumar con el contador    
        y=randint(1,100) #Se elige un número al azar    
        n=6 # Se determina la cantidad de números que va a tener el bucle z
        result=[] #Se almacenan los números generados por el bucle z
        for j in range(1, n+1): #Se crea otro bucle más para comenzar a iterar los múltiplos del número
            s=(y*j) #Se multiplica el número aleatorio con el bucle j
            result.append(s) #Se almacenan los números iterados
            op=choice(result) #Se elige un número al azar de la lista result
            result_total.append(op) #Se almacena el número correcto en la lista result_total
       
    v1,v2,v3=randint(20,150), randint(20,150), randint(20,150) #Se crean tres números aleatorios
    result1=[v1,v2,v3,op] #Se crea una lista y se introducen los números aleatorios y el número al azar de la variable op

    shuffle(result1) #La función shuffle revuelve la lista
    sel1,sel2,sel3,sel4 = result1[0], result1[1], result1[2], result1[3] #Se determinan las variables y se imprimen los números desordenados dentro de esas variables

    print(f'¿Cuál de los siguientes números es un múltiplo de {y}?') #Se imprime en consola la pregunta junto con la variable aleatoria que es un número
    print(f'a) {sel1}     b) {sel2}     c) {sel3}     d) {sel4}\n\n\n') #Se imprimen los incisos con los valores desordenados
    archivo.write(f'{up}.-¿Cuál de los siguientes números es un múltiplo de {y}?\n') #Se imprime en el archivo Ejercicio.1.11.txt la pregunta
    archivo.write(f'a) {sel1}     b) {sel2}     c) {sel3}     d) {sel4}\n\n\n') #Se imprime en el archivo Ejercicio.1.11.txt los incisos

up1=0 #Se crea otro contador que va a enumerar los resultados correctos
archivo.write(f'------------------------------------\n\n') #Se crea un separador para separar las preguntas de las respuestas
for w in range(insert): #Se crea un bucle para imprimir los resultados y el contador 
    up1+=1 #El contador comienza a sumar e iterar la numeración
    archivo.write(f'{up1}.-{result_total[w]}\n\n\n') #Se imprime en el archivo Ejercicio1.11.txt los resultados
archivo.close()
```

¿Hay alguna forma de corregir esto? Agradezco su apoyo.

Comment: ¿Cual es el error? ¿Cual es resultado correcto?

Comment: El resultado correcto es el que se almacena en `result_total.append(op)`

Comment: Pero me arroja un resultado diferente al que debería ser la variable `op=choice(result)`

Comment: Si no te das la molestia de explicarlo en tu pregunta, tu pregunta terminara cerrada por falta de detalles.

Comment: La pregunta es de bastante mala calidad. Deberías explicar qué hace el código en vez de dejar que el lector lo adivine. Deberías poner un ejemplo de la salida de la ejecución (para un caso en que el "Valor:" inicial dado por el usuario sea al menos 2), y al lado cuál sería la salida correcta. Por favor, mejora la pregunta. Por otro lado, el problema está en el bucle `for j`. Dentro de ese bucle reasignas cada vez el valor de `op` y lo añades a `result_total`, con lo que por cada pregunta tienes 6 respuestas válidas (pues j varía hasta 6), cuando solo debe haber una.

Comment: @CandidMoe ya explique con comentarios el código y también añadí más detalles a la pregunta

Comment: @abulafia pido disculpas por no explicar con detalle el código, pero en serio me cuesta explicar los detalles de una manera técnica, en serio, mis más sinceras disculpas. Ahora, hablando del código, tienes razón, hay 6 posibles respuestas que se almacenaron en `result_total` y solo una debe ser almacenada en cada iteración, pero al hacer otra iteración se vuelve a elegir otra al azar, ¿se puede corregir esto? PD: Lo voy a añadir la pregunta

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez. Los comentarios explican el código, no el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en este bucle:

```
        n=6 # Se determina la cantidad de números que va a tener el bucle z
        result=[] #Se almacenan los números generados por el bucle z
        for j in range(1, n+1): #Se crea otro bucle más para comenzar a iterar los múltiplos del número
            s=(y*j) #Se multiplica el número aleatorio con el bucle j
            result.append(s) #Se almacenan los números iterados
            op=choice(result) #Se elige un número al azar de la lista result
            result_total.append(op) #Se almacena el número correcto en la lista result_total
```

Entiendo que la misión del bucle `for j` es generar 6 posibles respuestas válidas (en la lista `result`), para **después** elegir una de ellas como buena. Pero esa elección no la estás haciendo después, sino *durante* la creación de la lista.

Por tanto tal como lo tienes `result_total` acabaría con 6 elementos cuando debería tener solo uno. Al terminar el bucle en `z`, los seis primeros elementos de `result_total` serían seis respuestas válidas para la primera pregunta, en lugar de ser una respuesta válida para cada una de las seis primeras preguntas. Por eso después aparecían respuestas sin aparente sentido (pero si te fijas en la respuestas que aparecían verías que eran todas respuestas válidas para la primera pregunta).

La solución es simple: mueve fuera del bucle `for j` la elección de la respuesta correcta, así:

```
        n=6 # Se determina la cantidad de números que va a tener el bucle z
        result=[] #Se almacenan los números generados por el bucle z
        for j in range(1, n+1): #Se crea otro bucle más para comenzar a iterar los múltiplos del número
            s=(y*j) #Se multiplica el número aleatorio con el bucle j
            result.append(s) #Se almacenan los números iterados
        op=choice(result) #Se elige un número al azar de la lista result
        result_total.append(op) #Se almacena el número correcto en la lista result_total
```

## Bonus

El bucle aún puede reducirse más, e incluso en cierto sentido eliminarse, si lo reescribimos usando una comprensión de listas. Quedaría así:

```
        y=randint(1,100)
        op = choice([ y*j for j in range(1, 7)]) 
        result_total.append(op)
```

Por otro lado tu código tiene justo antes un par de líneas que crean un bucle en `z` cuyo cometido se me escapa, puesto que tal como lo tienes:

```
    value=1
    for z in range(value):
```

el bucle en z itera una sola vez, por lo que perfectamente podría eliminarse.

Por otro lado no veo mucho sentido a la creación de las variables `sel1`, `sel2`, etc. cuando en realidad puedes perfectamente acceder a los elementos del array usando índices y ahorrando por tanto crear esas variables adicionales.

De la misma forma tampoco hay necesidad de la variable `up` ya que esta variable en el fondo puede sacarse del índice del bucle (más uno).

También deben evitarse las repeticiones literales. Tu código emite un mensaje por pantalla y poco después el mismo mensaje a un fichero. En vez de copiar y pegar el mensaje en dos líneas diferentes, es mejor crear el mensaje en una variable para usar esa variable dos veces. Así si cambias el mensaje sólo lo tienes que hacer en un lugar y aseguras la consistencia entre lo que muestra la pantalla y lo que va al fichero.

Otra idea de mejora es elegir buenos nombres para las variables. Por ejemplo, en vez de llamar a tu índice de bucle `o`, se le puede llamar `n_pregunta` que indica más claramente qué significa el número contenido en esa variable. Si eliges bien los nombres de las variables, el código será más fácil de leer y podrás ahorrarte comentarios que expliquen lo que hace.

Usando estas ideas tu código se puede *refactorizar* en la forma siguiente (la *refactorización* consiste en escribir un código equivalente, que hace lo mismo, pero que es mejor en algún aspecto, en este caso es más corto y en mi opinión más legible):

```
from random import randint, choice, shuffle
result_total=[]
archivo=open('Ejercicio1.11.txt', 'w')
insert=int(input('Valor: '))

for n_pregunta in range(insert):
    y=randint(1,100)
    op = choice([ y*j for j in range(1, 7)]) # Generar 6 multiplos y elegir uno
    result_total.append(op)
       
    opciones = [ randint(20,150) for j in range(3)]
    opciones.append(op)
    shuffle(opciones)

    pregunta = f'{n_pregunta+1} ¿Cuál de los siguientes números es un múltiplo de {y}?'
    respuestas = f'a) {opciones[0]}     b) {opciones[1]}     c) {opciones[2]}     d) {opciones[3]}\n\n\n'
    print(pregunta)
    print(respuestas)
    archivo.write(pregunta + "\n")
    archivo.write(respuestas)

archivo.write('------------------------------------\n\n')
for n_pregunta in range(insert):
    archivo.write(f'{n_pregunta+1}.-{result_total[n_pregunta]}\n\n\n')
archivo.close()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, un detalle así me rompió la cabeza. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos, los voy a aplicar ahora mismo en el código

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez De nada. He ampliado un poco más la sección "Bonus" con más consejos de refactorización. Espero te sean útiles!